# Can't make initial django migrations run

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

So I have this Django project from elsewhere (I didn't develop it).

It's set up to run in docker, I get everything up and running in my fresh environment and bash into the Django docker container.  I try running migrations `python manage.py migrate`.  Gives InconsistentMigrationHistory error.

I try running migrations for different apps at the same time.  I keep getting the errors.  Maybe important, but some of the errors are circular.  It's running migrations on app a, says it depends on app b, running it on b says it requires app a.

So I blow away the docker containers and rebuild everything.  This time I delete all the migrations before I do anything and run `python manage.py make migrations` first.  This runs fine.  Then when I migrate I get the same error, only this time it's a `Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency` error (originally was a specific app).

I've been using docker for a while but I don't think I've really delved totally into what it's capable of.  So the only thing I can think of is maybe deleting and rebuilding the container isn't resetting the database?  Just in case, here are the steps I took (four containers run and linked via docker-compose, Postgres, redis, custom build python for django, and an nginx for the static files)

1. Shut down docker-compose
2. `docker ps -a` Find the names of the 4 containers
3. `docker rm <each container found in 2>`
4. `docker-compose pull && docker-compose build`
5. `docker-compose up`

Any suggestions on where I should go from here?  There is no data to worry about, I can nuke whatever I need to to get this up and running fresh.

Comment: This looks like a problem with the migrations rather than something related to Docker or docker-compose.

Comment: Might try looking for stray Docker volumes (`docker volume ls`, `docker volume rm`, also `docker rm -v` when you're cleaning up the containers).

Comment: That was it!  Yeah there was a volume for the Postgres container, when I actually went in and looked in the actual database, what did I find?  Some tables from the failed migrations.  Blew away the volumes and started over, cleared migrations, recreated and it worked fine.